# Is there a figurative use to 春風?

Tags: idioms

I often hear 春風【はるかぜ】(or, much less often, 春風【しゅんぷう】) used to describe the characteristically windy weather of early Spring.

I was also certain I had heard it used on occasions as a *figurative* expression, to mean something akin to "Spring cleaning" or "Spring renewal".

However, when I look in both bilingual or Japanese dictionaries, I cannot find any such additional definition.

EDICT gives:

> 春風 [はるかぜ]  (n) spring breeze
>
> 春風 [しゅんぷう]  (n) spring breeze

And Wikipedia:

> 春風（はるかぜ）は、春に吹く風のこと。

Did I dream this figurative meaning? Is it merely understood and self-explanatory, but not widely accepted as part of the definition? Has anybody ran into a non-meteorological use of the expression?

Comment: Where did you hear it? Do you mean the discounts at shops that you frequently see in spring?

Comment: @sawa: not really sure where and how. Which is why I was trying to track down a reference. I guess discount signs might be one possibility...

Comment: For consideration: In Chinese there is one poem and there is one part: 野火烧不尽，春风吹又生. Which roughly translates to "is unable to be completely destroyed by fire; it grows again as the spring breeze comes." This matches your understanding of "spring renewal".

Comment: I am not familiar with the English expressions you mentioned.  Does “spring cleaning” refer to “the practice of thoroughly cleaning a house in the springtime” as stated in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_cleaning)?  If so, I do not think that the Japanese word 春風 has that meaning.  In Japan, thorough cleaning of a house (大掃除) is usually associated to the end of year, not springtime.

Comment: From just searching around online... it does look like 春風 can be used in combination with something like 新しい＋名詞 to convey the sense of "a new beginning."  If I can find a more formal example of this... I'll try writing an answer later.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: yes, 'spring cleaning' would essentially be 大掃除, though I know this particular one is associated with end-of-year... so it would be something a little different...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not quite be the same figurative use... but according to goo辞書, 春風 (at least when paired with 駘蕩{たいとう} [*peaceful* or *calm*],) can also imply a sort of refreshing calm, peaceful state:

> ２ 物事に動じないで余裕のあるさま。ゆったりとのんびりしているさま。<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> [goo dictionary source](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/106978/m0u/%E6%98%A5%E9%A2%A8/)